# Django debugging / verbose logging / other tricks

Tags: django, debugging, bitnami

I had a problem with a quite simple project. The description is below. My question is **is it possible to solve such problems ourselves (i.e. without deep knowledge of Django internals)?** Not by searching in the Internet, but by debugging or by examining verbose logs.

My specific problem was with ImageField. I have

```
class Advert(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='adverts', null=True)

class AdvertEditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Advert

def advert_edit(request, adv_id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        adv = get_object_or_404(Advert, pk=adv_id)
        form = TestApp.forms.AdvertEditForm(instance=adv)
    else:
        adv = get_object_or_404(Advert, pk=adv_id)
        form = TestApp.forms.AdvertEditForm(request.POST, instance=adv)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('TestApp:advert_details', kwargs={'adv_id': adv_id}))

    return render(request, 'adverts/edit.html', {'adv_id': adv_id, 'form': form})
```

When I opened page with this form, selected a file for upload and pressed submit, I got "This field is required" error and the same form with empty field (no file selected for upload). No errors in log/no uncaught exceptions - nothing. The solution was to add request.FILES parameter to the AdvertEditForm constructor call.

I use Eclipse with PyDev so I have an interactive debugger. But there is so much code that I was unable to find where the value is cleared or why it is not passed. Stopping on all raising exceptions also didn't help because there were too much exceptions

```
raise AttributeError(attr) in django/utils/six.py,
```

exceptions on

```
memo[id(memo)].append(x) in python/Lib/copy.py
```

and so on.

Comment: The last line of your stacktrace should always be where the exception happened.

Comment: @limelights, in this case I didn't get exceptions which caused problem. But you are right in that very often an error page is displayed and it contains very detailed description and stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You can use various forms of debugging, either shell, tests or you can also install Django debug toolbar which provides lots of information regarding your project.